Understanding the output of a simple neural network in TensorFlow Playground
I am learning about neural networks, so I started experimenting with Tensorflow playground.
to understand the basics I set all parameters manually and didn't train the model afterward. specifically I set the weights to 1 and -1, and the baises to zero. However, the output result surprised me, and I have alot of questions:

why is there a blue area in the output? Shouldn't that area have a vlue of zero and therefore be white?
If presence of blue area makes sense, why is it shifted upward and to the right?
why does the middle of the plot have a trimmed corner instead of a 90-degree corner?


